# How can I find which column is empty?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

```
SELECT ....
FROM   table_name
WHERE  a_column is null
OR     b_column is null
OR     c_column is null
......;
```

This is my SQL query. I took SELECT result but I dont know which column is empty and I took this result. However my table name and column names are dynamic. I can compile with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. I need to find empty column and after I should use this information. Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  What do you mean by "column is empty"?  A column that is `NULL` in all rows?

Comment: is there a possibility that more than 1 columns are empty? How do you wanna handle it in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to find out all the columns which are completely having NULL values, then you could query **[DBA|ALL|USER]_TAB_COLUMNS** view and check `NUM_DISTINCT = 0`.

**NOTE :** The statistics must be gathered up to date to get an accurate result.

For example,

Lets say I have table "**T**" which has two columns, `EMPNO` and `SAL` such that the `SAL` column is completely **NULL**.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM LALIT.t;

     EMPNO        SAL
---------- ----------
      7369
      7499
      7521
      7566
      7654
      7698
      7782
      7788
      7839
      7844
      7876
      7900
      7902
      7934

14 rows selected.
```

Lets **gather statistics** for safe side:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats(
  3      'LALIT',
  4      'T');
  5  END;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Desired output**

```
SQL> SELECT column_name,
  2    num_distinct
  3  FROM user_tab_columns
  4  WHERE NUM_DISTINCT = 0
  5  AND table_name     ='T';

COLUMN_NAME NUM_DISTINCT
----------- ------------
SAL                    0
```

So, you get the column which is completely NULL i.e. **num_distinct** is `0`.

---

**UPDATE** Based on OP's comment, it could be at least a NULL value.

- You could query the same view for `NUM_NULLS <> 0`.

For example, in the standard **EMP** table in SCOTT schema, let's look for the columns having **at least one NULL value**.

```
SQL> SELECT column_name,
  2         num_nulls
  3  FROM user_tab_columns
  4  WHERE NUM_NULLS <> 0
  5  AND table_name     ='EMP';

COLUMN_NAME  NUM_NULLS
----------- ----------
COMM                11
MGR                  1
```

Remember, the statistics must be gathered up to date.

- Another way in **PL/SQL** using **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE**:

Just reverse the `NULL` logic in the demonstration about [**Find all columns having at least a NULL value from all tables in the schema**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/09/25/find-all-columns-having-at-least-a-null-value-from-all-tables-in-the-schema/).

For example,

**`FIND_NULL_COL`** is a simple **user defined function**(UDF) which will return 1 for the column which has at least one **`NULL`** value :

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FIND_NULL_COL(
  2      TABLE_NAME  VARCHAR2,
  3      COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR2)
  4    RETURN NUMBER
  5  IS
  6    cnt NUMBER;
  7  BEGIN
  8    CNT :=1;
  9    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from ' ||TABLE_NAME||' where '
 10                                              ||COLUMN_NAME||' is null'
 11    INTO cnt;
 12    RETURN
 13    CASE
 14    WHEN CNT > 0 THEN
 15      1
 16    ELSE
 17      0
 18    END;
 19  END;
 20  /

Function created.
```

Call the function in **SQL** to get the NULL status of all the column of any table :

```
SQL> SELECT c.TABLE_NAME,
  2         c.COLUMN_NAME,
  3         FIND_NULL_COL(c.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME) null_status
  4  FROM all_tab_columns c
  5  WHERE C.OWNER    ='SCOTT'
  6  AND c.TABLE_NAME = 'EMP'
  7  ORDER BY C.OWNER,
  8    C.TABLE_NAME,
  9    C.COLUMN_ID
 10  /

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME NULL_STATUS
---------- ----------- -----------
EMP        EMPNO                 0
EMP        ENAME                 0
EMP        JOB                   0
EMP        MGR                   1
EMP        HIREDATE              0
EMP        SAL                   0
EMP        COMM                  1
EMP        DEPTNO                0

8 rows selected.
```

So, **NULL_STATUS** `1` is the column which has at least one **NULL** value.

Comment: Not completely NULL. For example just some rows are NULL

Comment: @FatihCeng Added two more examples.

Comment: Thank you so much @Lalit Kumar B  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `case` in select clause and output null column names as columns like below.

```
select case when o1+o2+o3 = 7 then 'a_column,b_column,c_column'
when o1+o2+o3 = 6 then 'b_column,c_column'
when o1+o2+o3 = 5 then 'a_column,c_column'
when o1+o2+o3 = 4 then 'c_column'
when o1+o2+o3 = 3 then 'a_column,b_column'
when o1+o2+o3 = 2 then 'b_column'
when o1+o2+o3 = 1 then 'a_column'
else 'none'
end as nullColumns, l.*
from (
SELECT 
case when a_column is null then 1 end as o1,
case when b_column is null then 2 end as o2,
case when c_column is null then 4 end as o3,
t.*
FROM table_name t WHERE a_column is null OR b_column is null OR c_column is null) l
```

Comment: Doesn't cover the possibility that multiple columns are null

Comment: Sorry  I updated my question. I forgot some information.Can you check it ?

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ...... FROM ' || dynamic_table_name || ' WHERE ' || dynamic_column_name || ;

Comment: dynamic_column_name : a_column is null OR b_column is null OR c_column is null.......

Comment: For example a_column is null and I took a result for X line. I want to write(with dbms_output) "a_column should not be empty". But I just know any column is empty but which column.

Comment: Good solution Utsav but my columns are dynamik. In that case my columns is sometimes a,b,c sometimes only a sometimes a,b,c,d,e sometimes f,g,h or etc. my column name change according to table_name and table_name is dynamic

Comment: create the whole select statement in a variable which will have dynamic column / table names. Then execute immidiate it.

Comment: Can you explain with syntax ?

Comment: just google `how to execute a dynamic select statement in pl/sql`. It is pretty straight forward. If you run into any issue while doing it, we will be happy to help.

Comment: I already know what it is mean execute in pl/sql :/  I think you didnt understand me or I didnt understand you

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE WHEN`:

```
select 
  case when a_column is null then 1 else 0 end as a_col_null,
  case when b_column is null then 1 else 0 end as b_col_null,
  case when c_column is null then 1 else 0 end as c_col_null,
  ......
from table_name 
where a_column is null 
or b_column is null 
or c_column is null ...... ;
```

1 means "yes" and 0 means "no" here. You could as well use strings, e.g. 'Y' / 'N' or 'TRUE' / 'FALSE' or whatever you prefer. (Only you cannot use BOOLEAN, as one would rather do, because Oracle lacks the BOOLEAN data type.)

---

You haven't edited your request. You haven't added an example. You haven't answered Gordon Linoff's and Utsav's questions. You should really learn to ask questions here.

What I gather from the information so far is that you don't want to look for *records* where a column is null (which is what you are doing with your query). You want to know whether a column is null for *all records*.

Below query gives you the column names of all columns that are empty for avery row in the table. So either you get back an empty string when everything is fine or you get one or more column names

```
select 
  trim(',' from regexp_replace(
    case when count(a_column) = 0 then 'a_column' end || ',' ||
    case when count(b_column) = 0 then 'b_column' end || ',' ||
    ......
  , ',+', ',')) as columns
from table_name;
```

Comment: Sorry  I updated my question. I forgot some information.Can you check it ?

Comment: With dynamic SQL this makes no sense, because what would the result rows actually mean to you? I think you should clarify what you actually want to see. I.e. answer the questions in the comments to your request.

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ...... FROM ' || dynamic_table_name || ' WHERE ' || dynamic_column_name ||  ;

Comment: dynamic_column_name : a_column is null OR b_column is null OR c_column is null.......

Comment: I know what dynamic SQL is. The question is: what result do you expect? Edit your question such as to show us an example.

Comment: For example a_column is null and I took  a result for  X line. I want to write(with dbms_output) "a_column should not be empty". But I just know any column is empty but which column.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Maybe I guessed right what you are after, maybe not. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to construct a list of columns that have values in at least one value in the table, you can do something like this:

```
select stuff((case when count(a_column) > 0 then ', a_column' else '' end) +
             (case when count(a_column) > 0 then ', b_column' else '' end) +
             (case when count(a_column) > 0 then ', c_column' else '' end) +
             . . ., 
             1, 2, '') as ColumnsWithValues            
from t;
```

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ...... FROM ' || dynamic_table_name || ' WHERE ' || dynamic_column_name || ;
Everything is dynamic :)